# R: as.name() - unsupported type symbol error"

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to join two `tibbles` together, by columns "GCA" and "model", but I got error:

> 'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical

So, as my `tibble` has those columns:

```
str(data)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  6 variables:
$ gc    : num 0.59
$ score : num 210
$ evalue: num 1.2e-55
$ inc   : chr "!"
$ model : chr "Chlamydo"
$ GCA   : chr "GCA_000091205.1"
```

And my columns of interest are characters, I tried this:

```
data %>%
 mutate_at(vars(GCA, model), funs(as.symbol))
```

But then I got this error:

> Error: Column `GCA` is of unsupported type symbol

However, when I'm trying it another way...

```
data$GCA = as.name(data$GCA)
data$model = as.name(data$model)
```

... it works!

```
str(data)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  6 variables:
$ gc    : num 0.59
$ score : num 210
$ evalue: num 1.2e-55
$ inc   : chr "!"
$ model : symbol Chlamydo
$ GCA   : symbol GCA_000091205.1
```

Byt then, when I simply want to view my data, I get this:

> Error in x[i] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Any idea of what's going on?

**EDIT:**

First tibble:

```
structure(list(gc = 0.59, score = 210, evalue = 1.2e-55, inc = "!", 
model = Chlamydo, GCA = GCA_000091205.1), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The second tibble that I want to join together:

```
structure(list(model_seq = "cuCacuuuga", sec_struct = "[[[[[[[[,,,", 
model = "Chlamydo", GCA = "GCA_000091205.1"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: please edit the question to include the tibbles (use dput(data) so they are easy to import) - this will make your problem possible to reproduce

Comment: Please can you also provide the other tibble you want to join `data` to?

Comment: If you use `str` on your second tibble, you will notice that the type is not the same. Could you describe how did you ended up to this tibble where model and GCA are names and not characters?